# intellij IDEA debug mode: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.debug.AgentPremain

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I am using intellij:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Ultimate Edition).
Build #IU-223.8214.52, built on December 20, 2022

Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.23 aarch64.  
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
```

The architecture is `aarch64`. And I am using Apple `M1 Pro` based MacBook Pro and the MacOS version is `13.1 (22C65)`.

---

My project is based on `spring boot` and I am able to run it as usual. But when I run the project in debug mode, I am facing below error:

> Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59789', transport:
> 'socket' Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> kotlinx.coroutines.debug.AgentPremain     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> at
> java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:431)
> at
> java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
> FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
> Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59789',
> transport: 'socket'
>
> Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

I have no idea why intellij is expecting `kotlinx` based classes. My project has no kotlin dependencies at all.

On looking at wiki - i see below

[image]

IntelliJ Idea itself is written in Java and Kotlin, so i think this issue is specific to the intellij idea `binary/version/architecute` i am using.

Could anyone suggest me how to get this resolved.

---

Note: I am able to run the same project in `STS/Eclipse` in debug mode, so definitely its not my project issue but intellij idea ide issue.

I raised a [bug](https://IDEA-debug-mode-Exception-in-thread-main-java.lang.ClassNotFoundException-kotlinx.coroutines.debug.AgentPremain) on jetbrains but believe more in sof, so this post.

Answer (score 3):

Well its resolved by jetbrains -

`Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Kotlin | Disable coroutine agent.`

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-24435